GitLab Pipeline for Unity on Kubernetes: Pod Initialization Timeout Issue
I'm setting up GitLab pipelines for Unity on a VPS using Kubernetes. When I try to run the pipeline, I encounter the following issue:
Waiting for pod gitlabrunners/runner-.... to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running: timed out waiting for pod to start. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information

Strangely, when I delete and re-add the GitLab runner instance with Helm, it runs successfully at first but eventually starts to show the error again.
Oh and i'm based on the work of a gitlab ci for unity, here are the links :

https://game.ci/docs/gitlab/getting-started
https://gitlab.com/game-ci/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example/

My Theories
1. Image too long to pull
The image is quite large, but I don't think this should be an issue because I expect the system to wait for the image to pull without timing out. When using my organization's runners, the image pull process did not have a timeout like this.
Here are the relevant logs and events:
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  7m15s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned gitlabrunners/runner-2z6aanszi-project-3625-concurrent-0-igflq9df to pgiacc
  Normal  Pulled     7m15s  kubelet            Container image "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-v17.5.1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    7m15s  kubelet            Created container init-permissions
  Normal  Started    7m15s  kubelet            Started container init-permissions
  Normal  Pulling    7m14s  kubelet            Pulling image "gitlab....:ubuntu-6000.0.19f1-windows-mono-3.1.0"

2. Not enough space
Although I have 22 GB of available space (34%), I suspect the issue might be due to the large size of the image and builds consuming all available space.
Here is the output of kubectl df for the GitLab runner holder:
kubectl -n gitlabrunners exec gitlab-runner-76cb9b6b7c-h9r4s -- df -ah
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  49.0G     26.5G     20.5G  56% /
proc                         0         0         0   0% /proc
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev
devpts                       0         0         0   0% /dev/pts
mqueue                       0         0         0   0% /dev/mqueue
sysfs                        0         0         0   0% /sys
cgroup                       0         0         0   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                     8.1G      4.0K      8.1G   0% /secrets
/dev/sda1                49.0G     26.5G     20.5G  56% /configmaps
/dev/sda1                49.0G     26.5G     20.5G  56% /etc/hosts
/dev/sda1                49.0G     26.5G     20.5G  56% /dev/termination-log
/dev/sda1                49.0G     26.5G     20.5G  56% /etc/hostname
/dev/sda1                49.0G     26.5G     20.5G  56% /etc/resolv.conf
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                49.0G     26.5G     20.5G  56% /etc/gitlab-runner
/dev/sda1                49.0G     26.5G     20.5G  56% /home/gitlab-runner
tmpfs                     8.1G      8.0K      8.1G   0% /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner
tmpfs                     8.1G     12.0K      8.1G   0% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
proc                         0         0         0   0% /proc/bus
proc                         0         0         0   0% /proc/fs
proc                         0         0         0   0% /proc/irq
proc                         0         0         0   0% /proc/sys
proc                         0         0         0   0% /proc/sysrq-trigger
tmpfs                     4.1G         0      4.1G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/keys
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/timer_list
tmpfs                     4.1G         0      4.1G   0% /sys/firmware


I had this issue because I put the gitlab token in runnerToken instead of runnerRegistrationToken. Hower i double checked and it's ok this time...

its neither the image pull nor the disk space. dump the container logs here. probably there will be something. would be useful also kubelet logs, if you know how to get them.

Here is the describe of the failing pod (the pod created for each run) : https://pastecord.com/qujamajodu.yaml
Here are the logs for the runner handler :
https://pastecord.com/otuvesuryx.properties (first part)
https://pastecord.com/isanybopow.apache (second part)

from df -h it didnt seem there were disk issues, but you might have. you can see in the logs it says the node doesnt have enough resources (specifying ephemeral-storage), and right after it mentions how kubelet didnt kill the pod within the grace period. so, I would say for being short in storage, kubelet kills the pod. but 20GB is a lot of storage to be filled in by a pod.

The base image is 12GB, and it needs to load caches/libraries of a unity project, the project isn't that big but unity always have a bunch of libraries so that adds to the runners (without adding to the final build)

oh... yeah, that might be the cause.

At first i had a PV of 10GB and doubled up to 20GB however it seems it didn't change a thing

Strangely, with a pv of 10GB, it didn't showed the issue earlier, aswell as getting some runs working some times to times

what type of PV? if it was tied to the host, you still pulled from the general pool, and still left the node without storage.

here is the pv and pvc declaration : https://pastecord.com/jifigagyny.yaml

yeah, that's a hostPath, which means it still gets the storage from the host. doesn't really matter with or without PV. Do you have a way to attach a secondary disk (around 40GB should be enough), and make that disk your PV. that would be a good thing as it will never starve your node storage, which is your root storage.

sadly i can't, its a VPS and i can't add much storage. i'll try to find a way to cleanup the data of my VPS and get back to you

Workaround/Solution found in this issue on gitlab : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/-/issues/560#note_1a6554148a64b08308e17607cec4df501d761b4a
Mainly the solution consist of setting the poll_timeout to 3600 in the values.yaml. This solution will still log a lot of containers with unready status however at some point it will have the time to pull the image and will set the status to ready.
